# How i can connect MongoDB online cloud in PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, mongoose

**i want online connection with MongoDB cloud in PHP**

same source file working properly when i run on localhost in my laptop with empty $server string while i use mongoDb server cloud then i face an error

```
<?php 
session_start();
// $server="";
$server='mongodb+srv://mongo_user_1:<password>@mongodb01-dolny.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority';
$mongo = new MongoClient($server);
$db=$mongo->blogPosting;
$admin_cl=$db->admin;
$category_cl=$db->category;
$blog_cl=$db->blog;
$contact_cl=$db->contact;
$blog_comment_cl=$db->blog_comment;
 ?>
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'MongoConnectionException' with
> message '- Found unknown connection string option 'retryWrites' with
> value 'true'' in G:\xampp\htdocs\mongo_blog\mongoDb.php:5 Stack trace:
>
> ## 0 G:\xampp\htdocs\mongo_blog\mongoDb.php(5): MongoClient->__construct('mongodb+srv://m...') #1
>
> G:\xampp\htdocs\mongo_blog\blog\index.php(1):
> include('G:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in
> G:\xampp\htdocs\mongo_blog\mongoDb.php on line 5

Comment: Try to connect to that database use some MongoDB client - for example robomongo or from terminal

Comment: What driver version are you using?

Comment: @PatrickQ its not localhost its online

Comment: @YasirMehmood  I'm not seeing a `retryWrites` option listed in the [MongoClient documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongoclient.construct.php).